# how to disable phpmailer showing configuration details on browser

Tags: php, email

I have no idea why the email configuration details and status shown on my page upon successful email sending. How to disable it?

The messages:

> SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP ss3sm18138445pab.43 - gsmtp
> CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mx.google.com
> at your service, [IP ADDRESS]250-SIZE
> 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250
> SMTPUTF8 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready
> to start 
> TLS CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost SERVER -> CLIENT:
> 250-mx.google.com at your service, [IP ADDRESS]250-SIZE
> 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
> XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
> CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 CLIENT
> -> SERVER: a2FsYWl2YW5pLmRjQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ== SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 CLIENT -> SERVER: bG92ZWlzbGlmZTg5 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235
> 2.7.0 Accepted CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<'email address'>
> .....................................

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set `$phpmailer->SMTPDebug=0;` to prevent showing debug messages.

Answer (score 1):

USE This php fuction  **error_reporting(0);**
and also use **SMTPDebug=0;**

By setting

**$mail->SMTPDebug = false;**

Comment: Tried, doesn't help...because it's not error..just information of server and so on

Comment: IF you does not make any changes in php mailer function then($mail->SMTPDebug = false;) it will remove error report